# check compound condition using OR and AND in php

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I want to check the condition either of one among $flag1==1 or $flag2==2 or $flag3==3 along with that $flag4 == 4 is true then I want to execute a statement.This is not working in php.I tried:

```
 if (($flag1==1 or  $flag2 == 2 or  $flag3 ==3) and $flag == 4)
        {

         $variable1 ='Change in Asset and Transformation Approach';
         echo $variable1;
    }
```

Comment: Maybe interesting to look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is a typo. You mentioned you wanted `$flag4` to equal 4. But you are checking the value of `$flag`.

```
if (($flag1 == 1 or $flag2 == 2 or $flag3 ==3) and $flag4 == 4) { // <-- notice $flag4
     $variable1 ='Change in Asset and Transformation Approach';
     echo $variable1;
}
```

[Working Codepad](http://codepad.org/Jlr8v8UZ).